# jQuery autocomplete select event

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

```
<script>
 var ArrayString;
  $(function () {
      ArrayString = <%=GetInstitutionsArray() %>;

      $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: ArrayString,
           select: function( event, ui ) {
           $("#Label1").val(ui.ID);
          }
      });

  });
```

I am using this jquery for creating an autocomplete list.. `GetInstitutionsArray()` is a function in the code behind that creates an object array that looks like this ..

```
 ArrayString = [{label: "Centre of Professional Training Sezimovo st",ID:9695},
 {label: "Kunshan Industrial Technology Research Institute",ID:10079},
 {label: "Gh Asachi Technical University of Iasi",ID:10186},
 {label: "KAZDIDAKTIK Ltd",ID:9427},
 {label: "3D Perception AS",ID:7796},
 {label: "A D PatelInstitute of Technology",ID:7390},
 {label: "A Star Singapore BioImaging Consortium",ID:8706},
 {label: "A James Clark School of Engineering",ID:9005},
 {label: "ADPatel Institute of Technology",ID:9151},
 {label: "AM AlKhorafi",ID:7296},
 {label: "AAI Corporation",ID:7795}];
```

I am trying to put the Id of the institution's ID in a label `Label1` when a label is chosen..

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The id isn't showing on a select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are incorrect here...

1. Is `Label1` the *client-side* `id` value of the element?  JavaScript operates on the rendered HTML, not the server-side ASP.NET controls.  You need to check what the actual `id` value is in that HTML.  Conversely, something like this might work by using the server-side code to dynamically populate the client-side `id` value in the jQuery selector:

   `$("#<% =Label1.ClientID %>").val(ui.ID);`
2. `.val()` isn't the jQuery function to use here.  A `Label` control renders as a `span` element, which doesn't have a `value` attribute.  Use `.text()` instead:

   `$("#<% =Label1.ClientID %>").text(ui.ID);`

   [See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/b8uS5/) and note how the call to `.val()` doesn't do anything for the `span` element.

Comment: @K.Habib: Can you be more specific than that?  What didn't work about it?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the selector finding the element you're looking for?  You need to provide at least *some* information.